# Exclude matched rows based on first column of two files

Tags: text-processing

I have two tab delimited text file. The larger main file 1 with multiple columns and the file 2, smaller file, that only share the first two columns for limited rows with file 2.

I want a file 3  as an output that exclude the rows that match between first column of these two files and print all other columns in file 1 as well.

I tried `grep -vf` but doesn't seem to work. please also note that I need match for both column.

file 1:

```
BP  CHR SNP REF ALT A1  OBS_CT  OR  LOG(OR)_SE  Z_STAT  P
1650048 1   rs112618790 C   T   T   12387   1.00246 0.0877604   0.0279678   0.977688
1856473 1   rs6684487   G   A   A   12387   1.02222 0.0836593   0.262689    0.79279
```

file 2:

```
BP  CHR
1650048 1
1650483 1
```

output (file 3):

```
BP  CHR SNP REF ALT A1  OBS_CT  OR  LOG(OR)_SE  Z_STAT  P
1856473 1   rs6684487   G   A   A   12387   1.02222 0.0836593   0.262689    0.79279
```

Comment: So your data only ever contains SNPs for chromosome 1? Don't you ever want _both_ columns from the files to match up?

Comment: yes, i need both columns (BP and CHR).

Comment: then [edit] your question to fix where it says `that match between first column` (note: **first** only). Right now the answers you have assume you meant what you said about that and because your CHR column is always 1 in your example we can't see a difference in your example (so improve that too).

Comment: [I see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/377370/motor-30) you've never accepted an answer to any of your questions. Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for how to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `awk`:

```c
awk '
    # set the input Field Seperator to a Tab
    BEGIN  { FS="\t" }
 
    # store column#1,column#2 of file2 into associated array bp_file2
    NR==FNR{ bp_file2[$1, $2]; next }

    # do not print lines of file1 if column#1 was in the array
                      # with FNR==1 we are printing the first header line too
    !(($1, $2) in bp_file2) || FNR==1

' file2 file1
```

Comment: this doesnt work : i also test this code that doesnt work:  awk -F"\t" 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]=1; next}  !a[$1,$2]' file2 file1 > file3

Comment: @motor30 see the edit. please also update in your question that you wanted match on both columns not only the first one

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the files are sorted on the first field, you may extract all records from the first file whose first field does not occur in the second file using

```bash
$ join -v 1 file1 file2
1856473 1 rs6684487 G A A 12387 1.02222 0.0836593 0.262689 0.79279
```

To retain the tab delimiter and the header:

```bash
$ head -n 1 file1; join -t $'\t' -v 1 file1 file2
BP      CHR     SNP     REF     ALT     A1      OBS_CT  OR      LOG(OR)_SE      Z_STAT  P
1856473 1       rs6684487       G       A       A       12387   1.02222 0.0836593       0.262689        0.79279
```

---

To match using both the first and second fields, create a new combined first field from these in both files and join on this field, then remove the temporary join field.  This basically implements a transformation similar to a [*decorate-sort-undecorate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), but with a relational JOIN operation in place for the sort.

The following code assumes a shell that understands process substitutions using `<(...)`.

```bash
$ head -n 1 file1; join -t $'\t' -v 1 <( awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { print $1 "_" $2, $0 }' file1 ) <( awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { print $1 "_" $2, $0 }' file2 ) | cut -f 2-
BP      CHR     SNP     REF     ALT     A1      OBS_CT  OR      LOG(OR)_SE      Z_STAT  P
1856473 1       rs6684487       G       A       A       12387   1.02222 0.0836593       0.262689        0.79279
```

Or, with a helper shell function to make the command a bit nicer to read,

```bash
$ decorate () {  awk -F '\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { print $1 "_" $2, $0 }' "$1"; }
$ head -n 1 file1; join -t $'\t' -v 1 <( decorate file1 ) <( decorate file2 ) | cut -f 2-
BP      CHR     SNP     REF     ALT     A1      OBS_CT  OR      LOG(OR)_SE      Z_STAT  P
1856473 1       rs6684487       G       A       A       12387   1.02222 0.0836593       0.262689        0.79279
```

Answer (score 0):

A python solution. May be longer than others, but more readable too (for me only?):

```py
file1 = '1'
file2 = '2'
separator = '\t'

list2=[]

# first building up a list of IDs from file2:
with open(file2) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0].isdigit(): # only process lines which start with number
            list2.append(line.split(separator)[0])

# then go through file1 and check IDs from the previously built list 
with open(file1) as f:
    print(f.readline(), end='') # printing out header
    for line in f:
        if not line.split(separator)[0] in list2:
            # print out line which IDs are not in list2 (not in file2)
            print(line, end='')
```

And run it like:

```
python3 file.py > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Perl:

```
 1  #!/usr/bin/env perl
 2  use strict;
 3  use warnings;
 4  use Getopt::Long;
 5  my ($once, $x, %x);
 6  sub k() {
 7      my @F = split /\t/;
 8      chomp(my $k = join $", @F[0, 1]);
 9      return $k;
10  }
11  sub usage() { "Usage: solution.pl -x excludefile [inputfile ...]\n" }
12  GetOptions('x=s' => \$x) or die usage;
13  die usage unless $x;
14  open (my $xh, $x) or die;
15  <$xh>;  # discard excludefile header row
16  $x{k()}++ for <$xh>;
17  close $xh or die;
18  while (<>) {
19      next if /BP\tCHR/ && $once++;
20      next if $x{k()};
21      print;
22  }
```

Line 1 lets the shell know this is a Perl script.

Line 2 "The strict pragma disables certain Perl expressions that could behave unexpectedly or are difficult to debug, turning them into errors."

Line 3 "The warnings pragma gives control over which warnings are enabled in which parts of a Perl program."

Line 4 loads the `Getopt::Long` module and imports its default functions.

Line 5 declares local variables:

- `$once` is a one-shot for printing exactly one header row.
- `$x` holds the value of the *exludefile* option (e.g. "smaller file"; "file 2").
- `%x` is a lookup table of input data lines not to be printed.

Lines 6-9 declare a function `k` for computing the value of the lookup table key from either an *excludefile* line
or from an input data line.  `k` is prototyped to accept no arguments; the *excludefile* line or the input data line is passed via the default input argument special variable `$_`.

Line 7 uses the `split` builtin function to divide `$_` into a list of fields, according to a regular expression for the field separator `/\t/`.  The resulting list is saved in the array local variable `@F`.

Line 8 uses an array slice of `@F` and the `join` builtin function to assemble the first two fields into a string, with the list separator special variable `$"` in between.  This string is saved into a local variable `$k`.  The `chomp` builtin function removes any trailing newline.

Line 9 returns the lookup table key.

Line 11 declares a function `usage` that is prototyped to accept no arguments.  As the code block does not contain any `return` builtin functions, `usage` will return the value of the last expression evaluated in the code block.  In this case, the usage message string literal.

Alternatively, the usage message could have been put into a `constant`:

```
use constant USAGE => "Usage: solution.pl -x excludefile [inputfile ...]\n";
```

A scalar variable is easier to interpolate into strings:

```
my $usage = "Usage: solution.pl -x excludefile [inputfile ...]\n";
```

Line 12 uses a boolean expression and the low-precedence `logical or` binary operator to do error handling for a function that returns *false* on failure.  First, `logical or` evaluates its left hand expression -- `GetOptions('x=s' => \$x)`.  `GetOptions` is a function imported from the `Getopt::Long` module.  The 'x' portion of first argument specifies that `GetOptions` should look for an 'x' option flag in the command-line arguments.  The '=s' portion of the first argument specifies that the option requires a string value.  The second argument, `\$x`, is a reference to the `$x` variable, which specifies where to put the string value.  If `GetOptions` encounters an error (omitting an option on the command-line is not an error), it prints a message to standard error and returns *false*.  In this case, `logical or` will then evaluate its right hand expression -- `die usage`.  `usage` is called, and the result is passed as an argument to `die`.  `die` will print its arguments on standard error and cause the script to exit with non-zero status.

Line 13 uses an `unless` statement modifier to do option validation.  If no '-x excludefile' option was provided on the command line, the usage message is printed on standard error and the script will exit with non-zero status.

Line 14 opens the *excludefile* using the `logical or` error handling idiom.  The `open` builtin function is called to open *excludefile*, creating and saving the filehandle in the local variable `$xh`.  If `open` fails, it sets the system error special variable `$!` and returns *false*.  `die` will then print the system error on standard error and exit the script with non-zero status.

Line 15 applies the `diamond operator` to the *excludefile* filehandle `<$xh>` to read first *excludefile* line.  This is presumed to contain a row of field names.  Because the read is performed in *null* **context**, the header row is discarded.

Line 16 uses a `for` statement modifier to iterate through the remaining lines in *excludefile* and build the lookup table `%x`.  The list of items to be iterated over (*excludefile* lines) is generated by applying the `diamond operator` to the *excludefile* filehandle `<$xh>` in *list* context.  For each item, `for` will place its value into the default input special variable `$_` and evaluate the statement `$x{k()}++`.  Function `k` computes a lookup table key from the item value.  The corresponding lookup table element `$x{...}` is **autovivified** and/or incremented by the auto-increment operator `++`.

Line 17 closes the *excludefile* filehandle using the `logical or` idiom.

Lines 18-22 form a `while` compound statement.

Line 18 uses the `diamond operator` on the null filehandle `<>` for the `while` expression, making the script a Unix **filter**.  For each input data line, `while` will assign its value to the default input special variable `$_` and evaluate the code block.

Line 19 uses an 'if' statement modifier to print the input data header row once.  The `if` expression uses the `C-style logical and` operator.   The `C-style logical and` first evaluates its left hand expression -- `/BP\tCHR/` -- which is a regular expression that matches header rows.  If the match is a success, the `C-style logical and` evaluates its right hand expression -- `$once++` -- which is a scalar variable with an `auto-increment` operator applied post-evaluation.  On the first occurance of a header row, `$once` will be undefined; which is false.  The `if` expression will be false, processing will continue with the next statement, and the header row will be printed by line 21.  But on the second and subsequent occurances of a header row, `$once` will be *true*, the `if` expression wil be *true*, and the statement will be evaluated -- `next`.  The `next` builtin function will cause `while` to stop processing the code block and proceed to the next iteration.  This has the effect of not printing the second and subsequent header rows.

Line 20 calls `next` if the key for the current line of input corresponds to a *true* value in the lookup table.  This has the effect of not printing input data lines whose first two fields match an entry in *excludefile*.

Line 21 prints the current line.

The solution produces the following output:

```
$ perl solution.pl -x file2.tsv file1.tsv 
BP  CHR SNP REF ALT A1  OBS_CT  OR  LOG(OR)_SE  Z_STAT  P
1856473 1   rs6684487   G   A   A   12387   1.02222 0.0836593   0.262689    0.79279
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "BP  CHR SNP REF ALT A1  OBS_CT  OR  LOG(OR)_SE  Z_STAT  P"}NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print $0}' file2 file1
```

output

```
BP  CHR SNP REF ALT A1  OBS_CT  OR  LOG(OR)_SE  Z_STAT  P
1856473 1   rs6684487   G   A   A   12387   1.02222 0.0836593   0.262689    0.79279
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
f1=open('/home/praveen/file1','r')
f2=open('/home/praveen/file2','r')
f3=open('/home/praveen/file3','w')
f1.readline()
f2.readline()

for i in f2:
    i_split=i.split(' ')
#    print i.split(' ')
    for j in f1:
        j_split=j.split(' ')
        if (i_split[0] != j_split[0]):
            str_append="BP  CHR SNP REF ALT A1  OBS_CT  OR  LOG(OR)_SE  Z_STAT  P"
            appnddata="{0}\n{1}\n".format(str_append,j.strip())
            f3.write(appnddata)
```

output

```
BP  CHR SNP REF ALT A1  OBS_CT  OR  LOG(OR)_SE  Z_STAT  P
1856473 1   rs6684487   G   A   A   12387   1.02222 0.0836593   0.262689    0.79279
```